# Powershell Try Catch in Function not working

Tags: function, powershell, exchange-server-2010

I have this function that never seems to trigger the catch block. It should trigger the error message when an Exchange cmdlet fails. Any ideas?

```
function Do-Mailbox {
     [CmdletBinding()]
     [OutputType([boolean])]

     Param (
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [string]$sAMAccountName,

         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [string]$Alias,

         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [string]$a,

         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
         [string]$AliasIndex
     )

    Try {
        Enable-Mailbox -Identity $sAMAccountName -Alias $Alias -ErrorAction Stop | out-null 
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $sAMAccountName  -ProhibitSendQuota 10GB -ErrorAction Stop
        ("" + $a + " User " + $sAMAccountName + " was assigned $AliasIndex " + $Alias + ". Mailbox " + $Alias + "@company.org created successfully.") | Tee-Object $Script:Report -Append
        Return $True
        }

    Catch {
        (" "+ $a +" [" + $sAMAccountName + "]", "There was a problem creating mailbox for " + $Alias + ". Please examine this account for issues.") | Tee-Object $Script:Report -Append
        Return $False}
    }
```

Comment: What is happening instead?

Comment: I see error on screen in red (say tries enable-mailbox but last name Jr.) but always Return $True message right after.

Comment: Can you show the exact error?

Comment: Property expression "JNavarroJr." isn't valid. Valid values are: Strings formed with characters from A to Z (uppercase or lowercase), digits from 0 to 9, !, #, $, %, &, ', *, +, 
-, /, =, ?, ^, _, `, {, |, } or ~. One or more periods may be embedded in an alias, but each period should be preceded and followed by at least one of the other characters. 
Unicode characters from U+00A1 to U+00FF are also valid in an alias, but they will be mapped to a best-fit US-ASCII string in the e-mail address, which is generated from such an 
alias. Property Name: Alias
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecifi

Comment: "each period should be preceded and followed".  Isn't that the problem?  The period isn't followed by a character.

Comment: The problem is the Catch not triggering in the function. I need errors like this caught and reported on. the Exchange cmdlets are 2010 and may not have the right functionality? The rest of the script process AD Users and this piece enables their mailbox and assigns an Alias.

Comment: My bad.  I saw that (and that you had -ErrorAction Stop) but got caught up in the cmdlets.  I don't know why the cmdlet isn't throwing an exception, but it sounds like it is writing to the error stream.  Can you test $? to see if it is registering that the cmdlet failed?

Comment: Yes, keeps coming back as True.

Comment: Does this help? Here's how I call the function;    If (!(Get-Recipient ($Alias0+""+'@company.org') -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) { 
     
        Do-Mailbox -sAMAccountName $User.samaccountname -Alias $Alias0 -a $a -AliasIndex "alias0"}